# WSO2 API Manager not working in AWS EC2

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have configured combination of API Manager and pre configured Identity server in AWS EC2 .
The problem is that API Manager internally refers to the private IP and its invoking the API using the private IP and the private IP is not accessible from internet.
suppose if i have /users/add API , when i use the swagger console , its trying to invoke the privateIp/users/add which is not working...
How to solve this?
I tried to hit using publicip/users/add ;but its neither giving any results.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your public IP or Hostname in `carbon.xml` for `HostName` and `MgtHostName`.

```
<!--
   Host name or IP address of the machine hosting this server
   e.g. www.wso2.org, 192.168.1.10
   This is will become part of the End Point Reference of the
   services deployed on this server instance.
-->
<!--HostName>www.wso2.org</HostName-->

<!--
Host name to be used for the Carbon management console
-->
<!--MgtHostName>mgt.wso2.org</MgtHostName-->
```

Also, you have to replace `${carbon.local.ip}` in all configuration files by required IP/Hostname too.

Comment: I did it..its startinig up in my public ip
But i am getting errror as 
DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://54.177.182.240:9712

 ERROR - DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://publicip:9712
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://publicip:9712
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:100)